# How to Display marker title for a few seconds after its creation and then remove it?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have a MapActivity in my Android application. I have added marker to a particular location as

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(values[1])
                        .position(stepsInThePath.get(Integer.valueOf(values[0])).startLocation));
```

But the title appear only when the marker is clicked.

**What I want?**

I want to show the title on the marker as soon as the marker is created (i.e, without clicking). The title should disappear after... say 5 seconds.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create bitmap or image dynamically using title and show as the marker on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
    final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(values[1])
                        .position(stepsInThePath.get(Integer.valueOf(values[0])).startLocation));
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (marker!=null)
                    {
                       //If you only hide marker title
                       marker.hideInfoWindow();

                      //If you want to remove marker
                        marker.remove();

                    }
                }
            }, 5000);//Millisecond for remove marker
```